# Santitize script src url value angular provides incorrect url value

Tags: javascript, angular, angular15, angular-dom-sanitizer

I need to sanitize the external url value to dynamically load script and remove script for specific component alone.

used following approch

```
private getUrl(): SafeResourceUrl {
    // declared value in environment file   
   return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(env.externalUrl);
  } 

public loadScript(): void {
    const scriptele= this.renderer.createElement('script');
    this.renderer.setProperty(scriptele, 'src', this.getUrl());
    this.renderer.appendChild(document.head, scriptele);
  }
```

I am expecting the correct script to be called in head section like
`<script src="https://urlvalue.min.js"></script>` // like this

but it gives as following with some extra text
`<script src="SafeValue must use [property]=binding: https://urlvalue.min.js (see https://g.co/ng/security#xss)"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [sanitize](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#sanitize) method with [SecurityContext](https://angular.io/api/core/SecurityContext) instead:

```
this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, env.externalUrl)
```

code:

```
  const scriptele= this.renderer.createElement('script');
  this.renderer.setProperty(scriptele, 'src', this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, env.externalUrl));
  this.renderer.appendChild(document.head, scriptele);
```